Nuxt starting Error: "[nitro] [unhandledRejection] content.startsWith is not a function"
Always when I start my Nuxt project I get this Error:
 at parseFrontMatter (/C:/IPA/md-files/node_modules/remark-mdc/dist/index.mjs:41:15)
  at parse (node_modules\@nuxt\content\node_modules\@nuxtjs\mdc\dist\runtime\parser\index.js:71:50)
  at parseMarkdown (node_modules\@nuxt\content\node_modules\@nuxtjs\mdc\dist\runtime\parser\index.js:94:10)
  at Object.parse (node_modules\@nuxt\content\dist\runtime\transformers\markdown.js:18:20)
  at transformContent (node_modules\@nuxt\content\dist\runtime\transformers\index.js:38:18)
  at parseContent (node_modules\@nuxt\content\dist\runtime\server\storage.js:193:18)
  at <anonymous> (node_modules\@nuxt\content\dist\runtime\server\storage.js:162:22)

When I understand it correctly something is wrong with the remark-mdc package. But the thing is, I uninstalled it...
I tried to delete and reinstall the other packages, clear the cache etc...
Can someone help me? Tell me if you need more information about my project...
package.json:
    {
      "name": "nuxt-app",
      "private": true,
      "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "preview": "nuxt preview",
        "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@nuxt/content": "^2.13.4",
        "@nuxtjs/mdc": "^0.11.1",
        "nuxt": "^3.14.1592",
        "vue": "latest",
        "vue-router": "latest"
      }
    }

when i delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file (in which i see the remark-mdc package) and then run npm i it got added again.

More details regarding your project are welcome. Also maybe try to delete the git repo and pull it from remote again.

@kissu Added more details from the packages. And i dont use a git repo... Its like a PoC for smth and only local...

The package is added again probably because it is a dependency of @nuxt/content. Did you gave a try to the 2nd post here? https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues?q=content.startsWith%20is%20not%20a%20function

@kissu yeah but didnt help...

@kissu Because its not a very big project, i just created a new one and copied the pages etc. it works now. Thanks anyway to invest time to help me.

I am confused. What was the solution then?

@kissu I still don't know what the right solution would be.  I think I just played too much with different packages and modules until something went wrong and I didn't work cleanly enough...
